# How to solve Could not find or load main class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader

I would like to build a java application.
System reported error message:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.autoparts.autoeshop.Application`

My controller:

```
package com.autoparts.autoeshop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I have written JAVA_HOME on system property.

[image]

Comment: which spring boot version you are using ?

Comment: And how are you running your Spring boot application ?

Comment: springboot version is 1.5.4.

I'm clicking Application.java right side "run as" -> Java app then getting error

Comment: there might be some cofiguration issue. what I suggest it to upgrade it to Spring boot 2

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is not completly correct as the `JAVA_HOME` should point to the installation directory (`jdk1.8.0_161`) instead of `bin` and the `PATH` should include `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`.

Your trial to compile with `javac` has been done from the wrong directory, you need to compile when you are in the `java` directory (including the relative path to the java file like `com/autoparts/autoeshop/Application.java`). Maybe your project has a build system prepared in the project directory (`autoeshop`) like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) (look for a `pom.xml`) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) (find a `build.gradle`)? If so, install the required build tool and run it, it will download all required dependencies and compile all the java files for you which is needed before you can run the application using the created jar file (typically found in a `target` (Maven) or `build` (Gradle) folder after the build tool ran.

Anyway, if you struggle with this kind of problems you may consider to start with some basic [Java](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html) or at least [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) tutorials.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181>javac com/autoparts/autoeshop/Application.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

It's not working

Comment: Did you add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to your path?

Comment: it's working.
Because I was wrong writing path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin meaning "\bin".
Correctly is "/bin".
Thank you